# Why does Haskell lack a literal Data.Map constructor syntax?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I'm still new to Haskell (learning it on and off). I'm wondering why Haskell doesn't have a literal `Data.Map` constructor syntax, like the Map/Hash constructor syntax in Clojure or Ruby. Is there a reason? I thought that since Haskell does have a literal constructor syntax for `Data.List`, there should be one for `Data.Map`.

This question is not meant to be critical at all. I would just like to learn more about Haskell through the answers.

Comment: Please let me know if this is an unconstructive question.

Comment: It *sort of* has one in that you can write `fromList [(1,"foo"),(2,"bar")]` to get a map that sends `1` to `"foo"` and `2` to `"bar"`. I know that this isn't actually a literal, but it's pretty close. It is a constant applicative form, so the function call can be optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: Yes, I agree that's not really cumbersome at all.

Comment: It's the wrong question.  The right question is why do lists have special syntax?  :)  (The answer is: it's a historical accident.)

Comment: Why you need special syntax for Map?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to the answers already given (the "historical accident" one notwithstanding), I think there's also something to be said for the use of `Data.Map` in Haskell compared to `Hash` in Ruby or similar things; map-like objects in other languages tend to see a lot more use for general ad-hoc storage.

Whereas in Haskell you'd whip up a `data` definition in no time at all, creating a class in other languages tends to be somewhat heavy-weight, and so we find that even for data with a well-known structure, we'll just use a `Hash` or `dict` or similar. The fact that we have a direct syntax for doing so makes it all the more attractive an option.

Contrast to Lisp: using `MAKE-HASH-TABLE` and then repeatedly `SETF`ing it is relatively annoying (similar to using `Data.Map`), so everything gets thrown into nested lists, instead—because it's what's convenient.

Similarly, I'm happy that the most convenient choice for storing data is creating new types to suit, and then I leave `Data.Map` to when I'm actually constructing a map or hash-table as an intrinsic component. There are a few cases where I think the syntax would be nice (usually just for smaller throw-away programs), but in general I don't miss it.

Answer (score 18):

Unlike Clojure and Ruby, Haskell's finite maps are provided as libraries. This has tradeoffs: for example, as you noticed, there's no built-in syntax for finite maps; however, because it's a library, we can (and do) have many alternative implementations, and you as a programmer can choose the one that's most appropriate for your uses.

Comment: On the other hand, we have the `OverloadedStrings` extension, why shouldn't there be a `OverloadedLists` extension as well? :-)

Comment: Would it be possible to create something with template Haskell that sort of gives you a Map literal? I'm not that familiar with how Haskell macros work so forgive me if that's a dumb question.

Comment: @Wes: pretty sure you can do that with TH — heck, you can even do things like SQL with TH.

Comment: @DanielWagner what is wrong with OverloadedStrings? It seems like a really cool idea, and seeing as numbers are overloaded and `[Char]` is often not the best way to represent text, surely it is useful? Would you say Haskell should convert numbers to `5`, `50L`, `5.0` and `5.0F`. This is not meant to be a jab I am genuinely curious, I am not experienced enough with Haskell to know all the downsides of such things.

Comment: @semicolon My comment was a bit tongue-in-cheek. However, there is some truth to it as well: `OverloadedStrings` hides a call to `fromString` in a way that makes it easy to forget it's there, which can cause surprising runtimes and surprising behavior; also, because of the simplistic type of `fromString` it is very tempting to write instances that do bad things like choose a terrible encoding or do some parsing when you aren't expecting it, and this temptation can also cause subtle bugs. Generally: "explicit is better".

Comment: @DanielWagner Ah ok; is the reason why it is not as dangerous to use overloaded numbers because `fromInteger` is much less dangerous than `fromString`? Also why can't one overloaded literal be used twice with a different type each time. `x = 5` `y = x / 5` `z = div x 5` doesn't compile.

Comment: @semicolon `fromInteger` actually shares *some* of the same problems as `fromString`; however, for some reason, extant libraries have mostly managed to avoid the temptation to do weird things in `fromInteger`. I admit I have no technical explanation for this outcome. For your second question, you may like to read [What is the monomorphism restriction?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32496864/791604).

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks for the help! If library designers avoid doing anything crazy are things like OverloadedLists and OverloadedStrings worth using? As they make it easier to write more generic code, and more generic pattern matching.

Answer (score 9):

Actually I'm not sure why nobody has pointed it out in an answer (there's only sam  boosalis' comment) but with `OverloadedLists` you can pretty much get literal syntax for `Map` and `Set`:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}

import Data.Map
import Data.Set

foo :: Map Int Int
foo = [(1,2)]

bar :: Set Int
bar = [1]
```

from there it's only one more step to get even nicer looking maps, for example:

```hs
a =: b = (a,b)

ages :: Map String Int
ages = [ "erik"  =: 30
       , "john"  =: 45
       , "peter" =: 21 ]
```

Although I personally prefer explicit over implicit, so unless I'm building a DSL, I'd still stick to `fromList` and `(foo, bar)` — Haskell is about the big wins not the small ones.

Answer (score 7):

Haskell has special syntax for lists because in a lazy functional language they more or less take the place of loop control structures in imperative languages. So they're much more important than `Map` in the grand scheme.

Also, I know you were referring to `[1,2,3]` when you said "list syntax", but I wanted to add that list *constructor* syntax could *almost* be implemented in haskell-98, in that type constructors can be infix when they start with `:`, e.g.

```
data Pair = Int :-- Int
```

So the list constructor `:` is just a *slight* special case of this general syntax rule, which is pretty elegant. Some people miss that.

Comment: ML (strict) also has special syntax for lists. Special privileges for lists are part of functional programming's history rather than deference to the lazy evaluation.

Comment: @stephentetley good point, thanks. But I think lazy evaluation is necessary for lists to replace loops (e.g. `while true; do`) and I think that's the fundamental thing about lists in haskell.

Answer (score 0):

Haskell does have a Map constructor, but it is "hidden" (like a private method in an object oriented paradigm). You are encouraged to use "public" constructors, such as *empty*, *singleton* or *fromList*.
However, if you inspect the code, available at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/src/Data-Map.html , you get the following definition

```
data Map k a  = Tip
              | Bin {-# UNPACK #-} !Size !k a !(Map k a) !(Map k a)
```

You can use the *Tip* and *Bin* constructors, but that is not recommended.

Comment: I don't think you can use the constructors, as `Map(..)` are hidden behind a `#if defined(TESTING)` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/src/Data-Map-Lazy.html)

Comment: Even if these constructors were "public", they would still have nothing to do with a hypothetical map-literal syntax — lists too have the constructors `[]` and `:`, and you are free to use them, but the literal syntax is sugar on top of that.